# About preview in xml file in Android Studio

Tags: android

I have installed Android Studio version 1.5, it is installed properly but in xml file it is not showing preview or design.

Comment: i thing 1.5 is tooo old version    yo can install 2.3.1  version of android studio.

may b its issue of JDK or latest sdk of android

Comment: post your android studio screen shot..

Answer (score 0):

You should update your Android Studio to 2.3.2, which is the latest stable release.

This enhances the compatibility with the latest SDK and API and should fix the preview problem.

To update go to:

> Android Studio -> Check for updates

[image: update]

If you want to download the latest stable release you can find it [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#latest).